# Pythonanywhere: imagenes con ruta correcta no cargan

Tags: python, flask

Tengo una pequeña aplicación en Flask que sube imágenes con su descripción. La imagen se guarda en un directorio especifico y la ruta se guarda en una base de datos sqlite junto a la descripción. Se muestran en una plantilla html.

Al cargar la pagina puedo ver que la descripción aparece pero la imagen no carga. Al inspeccionar puedo ver que corresponde a la dirección correcta;

```
/home/mysite/mi_nombre/static/imagenes/Galeria/la_imagen.png
```

En mis archivos puedo ver la imagen en esa ruta.
Sin embargo no carga en la pagina.

Pythonanywhere es muy claro sobre usar rutas absolutas en lugar de relativas. Al intentar guardar las imágenes usando `./static/imagenes/Galeria/la_imagen.png` me marca error;
 `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './static/imagenes/Galeria/la_imagen.png'`

Y la imagen no se sube.

Si alguien pudiese orientarme en el por que de este comportamiento para que pueda entenderlo y poder ver que dirección tomar para solucionarlo, le agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Prueba configurando esto en el settings #
## MEDIA_URL='/Direccion_media/' ##
## MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media") ##
*Ejemplo *,
### MEDIA_URL='/media/' ###
### MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media") ###
# Y luego agregalos en Static files de: Pythonanywhere:    #
   URL  --------------------------  Directory     
  /media/ ---------------------/home/Proyectos_yonatan/webyonatan/media/
```

Answer (score 0):

tengo el mismo problema con un formulario que sube imágenes en producción pero no las muestra con pythonanywhere, ya he configurado settings.py y los archivos estáticos de pythonanywhere (url y directory), y el comando python manage.py collectstatic en consola pero el error persiste luego de reiniciar el server para que guarde los cambios.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/349119)

Answer (score -1):

Cambia la ruta de `./static/imagenes/Galeria/la_imagen.png`  a  `/home/mysite/mi_nombre/static/imagenes/Galeria/la_imagen.png` , recuerda siempre poner la ruta desde la raíz.

si estas abriendo un archivo con `open()`, tambien debes usar la ruta desde la raiz